# Unable to extract text from Popup window

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to extract or get the text from the popup Window. I am using the below code:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of popup")).getText();
```

It is a div image popup (if that helps). I want get the text out the window and print it in the console. When I use the above code it just passes the test and does not get the text from the image.

Comment: Please add the relevant html code snippet here, or else if it is a public site, please give the URL and the steps to get that popup.

Comment: @ Subh..I added my code in the below comments wrote to @Thomas W.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply get text from an image. To get text from an image, you need OCR (optical character recognition).
The following should give you a starting point:

```
 URL url = new URL(imageUrl);  
 Image image = ImageIO.read(url);  
 String text = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still does not seem to work...here'z the code i tried... httpsURLConnection uc; 
 URl url = new URL ("URL Link");
 uc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openconnecion();
 uc.connect();
 Image image = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
 String text11 = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image); 
 System.out.println("Text From Image : \n"+ text11);...I am getting a javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL! 403..error..thanks

Comment: @VD: That's a HTTP 403 Forbidden error and not related to extracting text. Please make sure that you are logged in and do not use the URL from an old session.

Comment: @Thomas...Yes you are correct that's an http 403 Error...i got that error when I was trying to use the code you suggested...I am still not getting a fix for that after trying various options.